# Do data points mean Eigenfaces in higher dimensional space?

Tags: machine-learning

I saw the following animation at [making sense of PCA](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2691/making-sense-of-principal-component-analysis-eigenvectors-eigenvalues)
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNHqt.gif], which shows blue data points.

I am reading a paper on Eigenfaces which says that:

> "a typical image of size 256 by 256 becomes a vector of dimension
>   65536 or equivalently a point in 65536 dimensional space"

The paper is available at the following link:
[Eigenfaces for Recognition](https://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~mturk/Papers/jcn.pdf)

My question is that in the context of Eigenfaces is each blue point an image?

Somebody please  guide me.

Zulfi.

Comment: Please follow the link "making sense of PCA"

Comment: Yes, a point in 65536 dimensional space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each blue data point in the animated picture stands for an image of a face whose dimension is much higher in the context of *Eigenfaces for Recognition*. They are the original data points. It does NOT mean Eigenfaces.

When the long swinging black solid rod becomes still under the "viscous friction" exerted by the red lines, its direction is the most significant eigenface in that context, which is defined as an eigenvector of the biggest eigenvalue of the covariance matrix of the face images. The projection of the blue points onto that long black rod viewed as vectors starting from the center of the blue points is the first principal component.

Comment: Thanks Apass.Jack. I was asking "is each blue point an image?" and you have said " Each blue data point in the animated picture stands for an image of a face whose dimension is much higher". This means your answer is "Yes" . "They are the original data points. It does NOT mean Eigenfaces.". Yes Eigen faces are the Principal Components or Eigen Vectors. Thanks God bless you.

Comment: I am afraid that you got mistaken. The Eigenfaces are Eigenvectors. However, Eigenvectors are NOT principal components.

Comment: For example, how does [that popular answer at stats stack exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2691/making-sense-of-principal-component-analysis-eigenvectors-eigenvalues) describe principal components? "this new property is called 'first principal component'. And instead of saying 'property' or 'characteristic' we usually say 'feature' or 'variable'". Notice it is considered as a variable.

Comment: It is possible that some articles or some people may treat eigenvectors as principal components in some casual way. Indeed, they are so tightly related to each other it is almost impossible to mention one without mentioning the other. However, the general convention is that principal components are the **projections** of the original data onto the new axes. So, we will analyze the principle components (principle component analysis).

Comment: I got this from that stat site <We call these straight lines "principal components". There are as many principal components as there are variables. The first principal component is the best straight line you can fit to the data. The second principal component is the best straight line you can fit to the errors from the first principal component. The third principal component is the best straight line you can fit to the errors from the first and second principal components> Thanks for telling me that these are projections of blue points on to the principal axis. What we mean by variable here?

Comment: I just double checked that quote from [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/15195). That answer is exactly the case what I called "the casual way". That answer has been hailed by a few people as "best answer" and "a great and simple explanation". However, have you ever wondered why [the most popular answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/140579) does not use that kind of simple explanation with great-grandma, grandma, mother and daughter?

Comment: It is not used by [the second most popular answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/2700) nor [the third most popular answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/2698). Why? Because it might cause confusion down the road, even if it seems simplifying the explanation now greatly.

Comment: Suppose we have got all the data, eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Now how are going to analyze them? Please note that you can multiple an eigenvector by any scalar, it is still an eigenvector. So the length of an eigenvector is irrelevant to our data. We cannot "analyze" eigenvector in that sense. However, the projection of our data onto that eigenvector is significant. The lengths of those projection shows how strong and how varied the data is on the direction of that eigenvector.

Comment: We can compare the distribution of projections along different eigenvectors while it makes no sense to compare the lengths of different eigenvectors. So this projection of data along eigenvectors are really useful. That is the central idea. However, projection is a rather general word. So, let us use "principal component"  to mean that projection. The collection of these principal components ARE the data just as the coordinates of the original data. The only difference is that they are obtained from two different set of axes.

Comment: Indeed that answer in "layman's terms" has brought quite some confusion to you.

Comment: "What we mean by variable here?" Given any data point, we can get its first principle component (or the first coordinate in the new axes). So the first principle component can be considered as *an independent variable* as in statistics. So we can talk about its variance and its mean. Ditto for other principle components.